# Resolving Dependency in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a generic repository pattern on EF Core and I have a problem resolving the dependency of my Repository on Asp.Net Core. Using Unity i am Able to Solve the dependency here are my code:

**Using Unity**

```
 //here is the Line I Cant Resolve
.RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Movie>, Repository<Movie>>()

.RegisterType<IMovieService, MovieService>()
```

**Asp.Net Core**

```
services.AddScoped<IRepositoryAsync<Movie>, Repository<Movie>>();

services.AddTransient<IMovieService, MovieService>();
```

and I am getting Error

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync' while attempting to activate 'Repository.Pattern.Core.Repository`1[Sample.Models.Movie]'.
```

Can anyone has a clear documentation on how Native Dependency Injection works on Asp.Net Core

Comment: Well what is `IDataContextAsync`?

Comment: You've given me the Clue mate!! :)

Comment: Well the clue was in the exception message, I'll never understand why people ignore them!

Comment: See this for some working code: http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/

Comment: Also if you want to wire up your generic repo generically: http://ardalis.com/registering-open-generics-in-aspnet-core-dependency-injection

Comment: i was wondering what is equivalent to each Life cycle in containers of Unity = to type of dependency in .Net core. When I didn't make my repository scoped, data persistence is not pushed in the database

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` uses constructor injection to inject dependencies into resolved services. Your service locator needs to know how to construct these dependencies to produce the requested service.

Very basically if you want to resolve `IMyService` with a default constructor of `IMyService(IMyOtherService otherService)` you need to register `IMyOtherService` as well.

In your example you need to register `Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync` in order to resolve `IRepositoryAsync<Movie>`.

Comprehensive documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection